# How to adding item menus with the java script of an loop's sub menus inside like this example ".addItem("Go to This Sheet", "S"+i+"GoToS")"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, menuitem, submenu

Hy, Everyone .. I have a question about **creating the menu in GAS** (Google Apps Scripts) to implement to a Google Spreadsheet **without a three of the scripts** which is has been take long long way and take my energy too and many many so many lines of the scripts like this I have created. This is the script. Here's the code :

```
function Menu1() {
var ui = s.getUi(),
    s = SpreadsheetApp,
    ss = s.getAcgtiveSpreadsheet(),
    sss = ss.getSheets(),
    madeMenu = ui.createMenu('Sheet Tools Just For an Example Menus');

 for (var i=0; i < sss.length; i++){
   madeMenu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu(sss[i].getName())
      .addItem('Go to ...', 'S'+i+'GoToS')
      .addItem('Rename ...', 'S'+i+'RenameS')
      .addItem('Move ...', 'S'+i+'MoveS'))
   madeMenu.addToUi();
  }
}
```

```
function GoToS(getSheetNumber) {
  var sheet = sss[getSheetNumber];
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

**This of the main of my problems cames to !!!** *Because these structures of the scripts and then so to make me had to create this lines. See at the below :*

```
function S0GoToS() {
  GoToS(0)
}

function S1GoToS() {
  GoToS(1)
}

function S2GoToS() {
  GoToS(2)
}

function S3GoToS() {
  GoToS(3)
}

function S4GoToS() {
  GoToS(4)
}

function S5GoToS() {
  GoToS(5)
}
```

**The question is How to create them without the third-sub of the scripts ???** *I thought and I hope there is the another way to create these* for sure yes I believe there is but that just the because I don't know how about that way. Please someone chould be can help me to solve this case. Any achieves will be appreciated. Thanks in advance has taken in your time and I appologies for my poor english.

Comment: can I use like "**e.parameter**" this code to targeting the object to the menu by scripting in GAS ???

Comment: Hi. Have you actually executed any of this code? "Menu1", for example - what happens when you run that code? Rather than worry about the third part of this code, I think it would be more productive to come to grips with the basics of Javascript and Google scripts.

Comment: @Tedinoz Yeah .. But I'm the amateur programmer chould you tell me how ?  whould you write some lines to give me the exampale ...  Anyway when I run it. It just running supposes be like shows the menu of "**Sheet Tools Just For an Example Menus**" with the sub menu where the name of your collecting sheets had and then after run the "**Go to ...**" sub menus then will running the other script of "**S0GotoS**" the number has selected by an loop of javascript where the according with your sheet you selected on the first three of the sub menu ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in fact, generate those functions dynamically. The idea is to keep a for-loop **outside** of any of your functions, in the "global" scope, which will generate all these functions. Afterwards, they can be called by a menu action. Your could would look like the following:

```js
// function "constructors"
function createGoToFunction(sheetIndex) {
  return function() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[sheetIndex];
    sheet.activate();
  }
}

function createRenameFunction(sheetIndex) {
  return function() {
    // Your rename logic
  }
}

function createMoveFunction(sheetIndex) {
  return function() {
    // Your move logic
  }
}

// functions definition
this['ALL_SHEETS'] = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
for (i=0; i<this['ALL_SHEETS'].length; i++) {
  this['S'+i+'GoToS'] = createGoToFunction(i);
  this['S'+i+'RenameS'] = createRenameFunction(i);
  this['S'+i+'MoveS'] = createMoveFunction(i);
}
delete this['ALL_SHEETS'];
delete this['i'];

function Menu1() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var madeMenu = ui.createMenu('Sheet Tools Just For an Example Menus');

 for (var i=0; i < sheets.length; i++){
   var subMenu = ui.createMenu(sheets[i].getName())
                   .addItem('Go to ...', 'S'+i+'GoToS')
                   .addItem('Rename ...', 'S'+i+'RenameS')
                   .addItem('Move ...', 'S'+i+'MoveS');
   madeMenu.addSubMenu(subMenu);
  }
  madeMenu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  Menu1();
}
```

In order to implement your own functionality for the functions, you just have to change the body of them defined on top (see `createGoToFunction` as an example).

Comment: _**@carlesgg97**_  Wow ...  It's fantastic wonderful works now. How do you get that ?  Wow ...  anyway thanksfull for your successfully achievements. I've really really need to say a 1000 thanks for you. This was very make me to suprise and an excited really for me as a newbie this is something a proud chould get this important learning. Thanks once again Carlesgg97 ...

Comment: @jamalludin haha it was a tricky, interesting question... Glad you liked my answer! :)

Comment: _**@carlesgg97**_ Your tricky was very simple and innovatively and the shortest code I've found ever especially I haven't found the answer after was an over couple years ago since what I'd looking for these answer in this forum. Amazing !!! Yeah of course I'd like it. For my correction to learn to increasing in the near feature.