# How to write value and set all of sheet's Ids on the list of ranges by an loop's of javascript in GAS (Google Apps Script) to "A2:A" on Spreadsheet?

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How to write values and **set all of the sheet's Ids on the list of ranges at "A2:A" on google spreadsheet** *by an loop's of javascript* in GAS (Google Apps Script) ?

*Like here this is an example what I expected :*

```
        A         B         C
1  Sheet Ids Description
2  SEF32WTX  (sheet1)
3  XCXCSGS3  (sheet2)
4  XFSG33ER  (sheet3)
5  XFSGS23F  (sheet4)
6  FVDXDZ23  (sheet5)
```

*Here's the code I've tries to running on failed :*

```
function writeAllSheetIds() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp,
      ss = s.getAcgtiveSpreadsheet(),
      sss = ss.getSheets(),
      range = ss.getRange("A2:A");
  for (var i=1, iLen=sss.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    range.setValues(sss[i].getSheetId());
    }
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried running the code sample shown here? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets

Comment: _**@Diego**_   Yeah, I do I have but it still just amateur code I'm a beginner. Chould  you want some to tell me how to fix this code. Here's the code:

`function writeAllSheetIds() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp,
      ss = s.getAcgtiveSpreadsheet(),
      sss = ss.getSheets(),
      range = ss.getRange("A2:A");
  for (var i=1, iLen=sss.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    range.setValues(sss[i].getSheetId());
    }
}`

Comment: This is a variation on a theme - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58985761/1330560.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function writeAllSheetIdsAndSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function(s){SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([s.getSheetId(),s.getName()])});
}
```

For those wishing to specify a sheet by name:

```
function writeAllSheetIdsAndSheets1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function(s){SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").appendRow([s.getSheetId(),s.getName()])});
}
```

Comment: _**@Cooper**_ Wow it's wonderful works so far. But Cooper! anyway I can't modified it into particular target sheet such as : "**SpreadsheetApp.getSheets()[2].appendRow...**" Chould I do this occur ???

Comment: _**@Cooper**_ **No.. no .. no .. I pull it back my words above! Finally. It's really completely fantastic works ...**

Comment: _**@Cooper**_ may I ask you again how if we want to make this as a custom function and call it to spreadsheet cell like a formulas ???   e.g :  "=writeAllSheetIdsAndSheets()" ...

Comment: It can't be a cell function because it doesn't return anything and it changes the contents of other cells.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: _**@Cooper**_ Hy, Cooper! I can use it as a cunstom function now but it won't looping them what I'd created on their an above ... Which is when I call the custom function like this "**=setSheetIdhere()**" the output come just give me or came out with something result like of the single cell data of the result only that the value is "**0**".

` function setSheetIdhere() { for (var i=0; i < sss.length; i++) { return [[sss[i].getSheetId()]]; } } `